# Cannot get lldb location to resolve

Tags: cmake, lldb

I am attempting to compile and debug from the command line, using cmake and lldb. I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (etest)
include_directories(src)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -g")
add_executable(etest src/m.cpp)
set_property(TARGET etest PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_property(TARGET etest PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

Then:

```
~/Desktop/em2 cmake .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/jbake/Desktop/em2
~/Desktop/em2 make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/etest.dir/src/m.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable etest
[100%] Built target etest
~/Desktop/em2 lldb etest 
(lldb) target create "etest"
Current executable set to 'etest' (x86_64).
(lldb) b src/m.cpp:7
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) breakpoint list
Current breakpoints:
1: file = 'src/m.cpp', line = 7, locations = 0 (pending)
```

I thought the `-g` option was necessary to get debug locations added to the executable for use with lldb, but I've been trying various tweaks for hours and cannot get anything to resolve. What am I missing?

Comment: What compile options shows `make VERBOSE=1` when compile executable? `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` adds new flags, but doesn't remove configuration-specific options.

Comment: @Tsyvarev what I discovered is that i need to reference the path in the cmake file, but only if i remove the `src/` from the lldb breakpoint, then it finds it. this seems strange to me. I guess if I had two sources with the same name, then either it would require the directory or it would set the same breakpoint in both files. i'll have to experiment. but otherwise, the path is not part of the filename and should be omitted

Comment: In any case, knowing compilation line would help a lot. It is possible that CMake copy source file into some directory under build tree, and then build it there. Such a way it losts path prefixes. Another possibility, that it uses absolute path to source file for compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in lldb that means you either have to set a breakpoint with JUST the file name, or you have to use the full path as recorded in the debug information.  Partial paths should work, but don't at present.

Using full paths is tricky if you have a build system that moves files around or refers to them through symbolic links.  Then you have to get the path as spelled to the compiler.  You can find this by doing:

```
(lldb) break set -f JustTheName.cpp -l 10
```

Then grab the address that the breakpoint was set at, and do:

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -a <BREAK_ADDRESS>
```

The file in the CompileUnit part of this output will be the path as spelled in the debug information.

Comment: Hours of debugging later and I finally find this! Thank you!